# How to fetch the data from database using OOPS and PDO concepts in PHP

Tags: php

How to fetch the data from database using OOPS and  PDO concepts in PHP :
       I want to retrieve the data from database and display in views-one .php page
        using OOPS and  PDO concepts.

```
**controller-one ** 
<?php
public function display_reports()           // declaring function
 {
try { 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM date WHERE 1";      //query selection

  $query = $this->db->prepare($sql); 
  $query->execute();   
  $data=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //fetching the data from the table

while($row = $query->fetch()){  //i am getting error here

  $id = $row->event_id;         //fetching one coloumn
  $start = $row->start_date;     //fetching one coloumn
  }
}catch (Exception $e) {

} ?>
```

created the function in above and calling here to display in webpage,

```
  **views-one **
 $rows = $this->reportsmodel->display_reports();      //calling function here
                id
                <?php echo $rows->$id;?>              //trying to display the content here
                Start
                <?php echo $rows->$start; ?>           //trying to display the content here
```

here i am getting errors these 2 eerors,
         Notice: Undefined variable: id ,
         Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
         Notice: Undefined variable: start
         Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
        I want to display data in loop. I am new to OOPs in PHP and i want to practice                          more. i try to use while and for loop.i am not getting data.can anyone help me with this? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a solution :

```
public function display_reports(){
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM date WHERE 1"); 
    $query->execute();  

    return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // return an array of objects
}


// In the view
$rows = $this->reportsmodel->display_reports();

foreach($rows as $row){ //for each object in the array
    echo $row->id;
}
```

Comment: Please, check the answer as correct to help other users.